# Regular Expressions If Else

Tags: php, regex

I have a string: **/foo/{bar}/{baz?}**

Now i want to extract all words inside the {...}.
But on the word with the "?" i want to select not only the {...} but also the "/" before "{"

So far i got this:

```
$string = '/foo/{bar}/{baz?}';

preg_match_all('~{(\w+)[?]?}~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {bar}
            [1] => {baz?}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
            [1] => baz
        )

)
```

But should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {bar}
            [1] => /{baz?}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
            [1] => baz
        )

)
```

**(Notice the / before the {baz?} match)**

Hope this is clear enough my english is not so good.
Thanks

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans if a pattern is _regular_ a regular expression will be able to match it. This pattern seems regular so it's fine. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans its for a routing system im building

Comment: @Halcyon thank you for correcting me! I'll delete the respective comment.

Comment: PHP is a full blown programming language, why not just use PHP's if/else instead of trying to get Regex to do something it's not well suited to?  Aside from anything else PHP is more expressive than regex so it will be easier to figure out what it's trying to do when you look at the code in the future.

Comment: This regex could be of help: `~(((/{[^}]*\?})|{[^}]*}))~` although it is hard to read it. There is an outer line defining "or" `(this|that)`. "This" is a capture group for something starting with / and containing {smth?} `(/{[^}]*\?})`. The `[^}]*` part will match everthing until next closing curly bracket. Than you have "that" capture group that does not contain question mark and therefore does not match the slash (or if you just want to match any character before curly bracket switch slash for dot).

Comment: @ViliamAboši your regexp will also match `{abc?}` without the leading forward slash. I don't think that was intended. You also have unnecessary brackets. It also matches `{}`.

Comment: @Halcyon it wasn't meant as an exact solution, but rather an approach. To tell the truth I am not sure what exactly does Tafelglother want to match and capture. If only the inside of curly brackets or the brackets themselves too.

Comment: There is a way to find out what he wants but some people use that space to post kinda half baked answers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [**branch reset group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) (`(?|...|...)`) with 2 capturing groups inside that will share the same ID:

```
/(?|\/{(\w+)\?}|{(\w+)})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k2wrKr/1)

**Details**:

- `(?|` -  branch reset group start
- `\/{(\w+)\?}` - a `/{`, then   1+ word chars (captured into Group 1) and then `?}`
- `|` - or
- `{(\w+)})` - a `{` followed with 1+ word chars (captured into Group 1 again) and then `}`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/jSuJNV):

```
$re = '/(?|\/{(\w+)\?}|{(\w+)})/';
$str = '/foo/{bar}/{baz?}';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);
```